# How to use caller ID instead of "s" in SIP refer method?

Tags: sip, voip

I'm working on script for automated calls via SIP and ran into a problem with the Caller ID.

The script runs quite simple:

1. Calls the customer by his phone (for example, +1234567890) via INVITE method
2. When the customer answers the call, uses REFER method to transfer the call to his personal manager.
3. Manager receives the incoming call with the dialog established with the customer.

At the step 2-3 manager always receives the call from the contact called s@1.2.3.4 (where 1.2.3.4 is the IP address of our SIP server). How can I set the customers phone instead of `s@1.2.3.4` ?

The refer request I use looks like this:

```
REFER sip:+1234567890@1.2.3.4:5060 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.1.1:5100;rport;branch=z9hG4bK160892
From: <sip:100@192.168.1.1>;tag=29899
To: <sip:+1234567890@1.2.3.4:5060>
Call-ID: 28990ec994a682147cf87eda75f97664@192.168.1.1
CSeq: 22 REFER
Contact: <sip:100@192.168.1.1:5100>
Max-Forwards: 70
Refer-to: sip:111@1.2.3.4
Referred-By: <sip:+1234567890@1.2.3.4:5060>
Content-Length: 0
```

Here 100 is SIP ID of the call robot, 192.168.1.1 is the IP of robot, 111 is SIP ID of manager.

I tried using Refer-To like these:

```
Refer-to: <sip:111@1.2.3.4?Call-ID=28990ec994a682147cf87eda75f97664@192.168.1.1&From=%3Csip%3A%2B1234567890%401.2.3.4%3A5060%3E&Contact=%3Csip%3A%2B1234567890%401.2.3.4%3A5060%3E>
Refer-to: <sip:111@1.2.3.4?Call-ID="69ca6b4e1874aa07569ee234cf746a3c@192.168.1.1"&From="<sip:+1234567890@1.2.3.4:5060>"&Contact="<sip:+1234567890@1.2.3.4:5060>">
Refer-to: <sip:111@1.2.3.4;method=INVITE?Call-ID="d71d3cc87f88eb1522859296889d39fb@192.168.1.1"&From="sip:+1234567890@1.2.3.4:5060"&Contact="<sip:+1234567890@1.2.3.4:5060>">
```

But nothing worked as I expected, caller ID of the incoming manager's call still was `s@1.2.3.4`. The correct caller ID is required for us to get call recordings.

SIP software used: Kerio Operator (based on Asterisk).

What Refer-To or other headers can I use to send the correct caller ID?

Answer (score 1):

First some remarks regarding the REFER request:

- The Referred-By header should contain the referrer's SIP URI, not the referee's SIP URI.
- The REFER request should be sent within the existing dialog. It appears you send the REFER request outside of any dialog (no to-tag provided).

From your description I derive that you use a B2B SIP server. That means when the customer's phone (+1234567890@1.2.3.4) receives the REFER request, the resulting INVITE request will be sent to the SIP server (s@1.2.3.4). The SIP server will then create a new INVITE request and send this to the manager's phone (111@1.2.3.4).

The INVITE request from SIP server to manager's phone will contain the following values:

- to header --> 111@1.2.3.4
- from header --> +1234567890@1.2.3.4
- contact header --> s@1.2.3.4

The manager's phone then has to use the from header's value as caller ID, not the contact header's value.

You might want to check

- if the INVITE request contains the right header values
- if the manager's phone uses the right header to determine the caller ID.

I hope this helps.